# Build error using Apache Avro generated files

Tags: java, gradle, avro

I a using Gradle to build a simple app using Apache Avro. Following are the relevant files:

File `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.9.0"
}

apply plugin: 'application'

group 'ahmed'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

avro {
    createSetters = false
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
}

mainClassName = 'App'
```

File `src/main/avro/com/ahmed/pb/Employee.avsc`

```
{"namespace": "com.ahmed.pb",
  "type": "record", "name": "Employee",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "firstName", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "lastName", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "age",  "type": "int"},
        {"name": "phoneNumber",  "type": "string"}
    ]
}
```

File: `src/main/java/App.java`

```
// import avro.com.ahmed.pm.*;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello world.";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());


        Employee bob = Employee.newBuilder().setAge(35)
                .setFirstName("Bob")
                .setLastName("Jones")
                .setPhoneNumber("555-555-1212")
                .build();

        assertEquals("Bob", bob.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Build error message:

```
$ ./gradlew  run
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:generateAvroProtocol NO-SOURCE
:generateAvroJava
:compileJava
/home/ahmed/temp/avrotut/src/main/java/App.java:5: error: package avro.com.ahmed.pm does not exist
import avro.com.ahmed.pm.*;
^
/home/ahmed/temp/avrotut/src/main/java/App.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Employee bob = Employee.newBuilder().setAge(35)
        ^
  symbol:   class Employee
  location: class App
/home/ahmed/temp/avrotut/src/main/java/App.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Employee bob = Employee.newBuilder().setAge(35)
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Employee
  location: class App
Note: /home/ahmed/temp/avrotut/build/generated-main-avro-java/com/ahmed/pb/Employee.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 errors
:compileJava FAILED
```

I am having a hard time including the Java generated class. Do I need to add some dependency in the `build.gradle` file? The import line in `App.java` is not working also.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @hlagos I updated the post with the build error.  What I am trying to find out is how to add the proper import and/or any dependency for avro generated java classes.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you try and put your avsc file in the dir 'src/main/avro/Employee.avsc' instead of 'src/main/avro/com/ahmed/pb/Employee.avsc'. And also import your generated Employee class based on the defined namespace: import com.ahmed.pb.Employee

Comment: @niekname I did not have to move the Employee.avsc location.  There was a silly typo in the import statement.  It is working now. Thank you very much for helping out.  (I noticed the typo after copying and pasting the import statement from your post).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a typo in the spelling of the full package name.  Closing this question as solved.